# Mysql database connection file errors

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mysqli, amazon-ec2

I am on an Amazon ec2 instance and I have a database that I am trying to access via a PHP script.  I am echoing out tests through the script so i seem to get to the end but I am not getting any errors.  Whenever I change my localhost to my IP it says: Connection error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'MY IP' (110).  I have tried binding my localhost and server server IP to my.cnf file and still the same result.  Are there any other configurations I am missing?  I have never had this much trouble before but this is my first time working on an amazon ec2 Linux instance.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database");

if (!$con)
{
die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "testing1";


$query = "SELECT id, email FROM user_key ORDER BY email DESC LIMIT 10;";

echo "here";

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "here2";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 echo $row['id']." ";
 echo $row['email']." ";
}

echo "last";
?>
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear: connecting from where to where does work, and connecting from where to where does not work?

Comment: Well connecting with "localhost" doesn't throw any errors but it also doesn't echo out any of my data.  If i use my server IP then I get this error: Connection error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'Server IP' (110)

Comment: What is the output from `sudo netstat -nap | grep tcp | grep LISTEN | grep 3306`?

Comment: Result :    http://imgur.com/a/O178U

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: I jsut tried it using PDO and had the same result.  Localhost didn't output my data and my server IP had the same connection error.